# Is there a way to put a condition on BatchWriteItems ?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to put a condition on BatchWriteItems ? I need to put items only if they don't exist.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think so.

from the BatchWriteItem [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html)

"In order to improve performance with these large-scale operations, BatchWriteItem does not behave in the same way as individual PutItem and DeleteItem calls would For example, you cannot specify conditions on individual put and delete requests, and BatchWriteItem does not return deleted items in the response."